# How to set system properties in C

Tags: c, proxy

How can I set system properties in C.

In **Java** I can use :

```
System.setProperty("java.net.useSystemProxies", "true");
```

How can I do it using C language ?

Comment: System Properties aren't really a thing in C. They're not really "System" properties either, they're JVM wide settings.

Comment: Could you elaborate what you want to achieve? Do you want to edit some Windows registry value, save a setting for another program, ... ?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to modify processes environment? In this case you should have a look at `putenv`/`getenv` functions under Linux. Environment variables are string values denoted by identifiers. Some variables are standardized on Unix as `TERM`, `PATH`, `PS1`, etc. That set of variables is inherited through `fork`/`exec`.

Things could be (very) different on other systems.